# Dependency injection for non controller classes and calling them

Tags: .net-core, dependencies

Trying to wrap my head around dependency injection, coming from the world of static classes and instantiated classes. Here is what I currently have:

```
[SomeFilter]
public class AController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;

    public AController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    _appSettings = appSettings;
}

// GET: /characters/
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //do something
}
```

SomeFilter gets called immediately, and does this:

```
public class SomeFilter: ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       OtherClass.RunMe();
    }
}
```

OtherClass looks like this:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;

    public OtherClass(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    _appSettings = appSettings;
}

public RunMe()
{
    //do something
}
```

I also have OtherClass registered as a service.Singleton in the Startup.cs.

I get an error stating:

> "An object reference is required for a non-static field"

for the `OtherClass.RunMe();` call.

I was under the assumption that I can call this class from anywhere within my code instead of having to create a new instance of it? Essentially, how do I call methods from other classes using dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

You can't constructor injection on filters. It's all about run time order. When you try injection on constructor, your IoC container not reachable at the moment. You should be use property/setter injection.

I prefer using structuremap container for to do this. Because structuremap has very easy to apply any type injection. For example when you have a filter registry like this

```
 public class ActionFilterRegistry : Registry
    {
        public ActionFilterRegistry(Func<IContainer> containerFactory)
        {
            For<IFilterProvider>().Use(
                new StructureMapFilterProvider(containerFactory));

            Policies.SetAllProperties(x =>
                x.Matching(p =>
                    p.DeclaringType.CanBeCastTo(typeof(ActionFilterAttribute)) &&
                    p.DeclaringType.Namespace.StartsWith("YourNameSpace") &&
                    !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive &&
                    p.PropertyType != typeof(string)));
        }
    }
```

And you register it on your global.asax(prefer) or one of your startup class.
Example app_Start method.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(() => Container ?? ObjectFactory.Container));
            ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddRegistry(new StandardRegistry());
                cfg.AddRegistry(new ControllerRegistry());
                cfg.AddRegistry(new ActionFilterRegistry(() => Container));
                cfg.AddRegistry(new MvcRegistry());                
            });
```

Then you can use any filter with injection. But pay attention you shouldn't be use contructor injection like you do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to inject into the filter by using

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyFilter))]
```

instead of just

```
[MyFilter]
```

and within the filter's

```
(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var controller = context.Controller as Controller.  
    controller.whateverIneed
}
```

This now provides me with what I need within the filter.  What I also realized is that I can't remove the need for creating references to other classes using `new`, as I was under the impression Core's dependency was all about "no more `new`".  This gets into fundamentals with Core which I'm still grasping with.

What I ended up doing was creating new classes that do some work, but they are setup as *services* and registered in the startup.cs.  I'm still grappling on how to intermingle registered services (which I can inject) and new instances of worker classes (which usually hold static information), and passing information between them all.